# Jupyter-lab accesses a different Python/terminal version than the terminal itself. Why and how to fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab

I'm using macOS Ventura 13.2. In the console, I get...

```
> which python
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3

> which jupyter-lab
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/jupyter-la
```

...but within JupyterLab, I get a mix:

```
> import sys
> sys.executable
'/usr/local/bin/python3'

> !python -V
Python 2.7.14
```

Comment: Ideally, you'd be using environments to manage your Python and Jupyter kernels. (You can choose to connect to the kernels in the environment from inside Jupyter when you have it all working right.) Having environments for each project to insure reproducibility in the long run while allowing you flexibility to try new packages, all without messing up the base Python on your system. Jupyter is using something different because you maybe are using different package managers now? You used homebrew for one you see in the console and a different one, maybe `pip`, for `/usr/local/bin/python3`?

Comment: Installing [the Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution) provides a lot of that functionality. See about making and activating environments in it [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment). Others prefer more control choose mamba and or miniconda , see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/module-versions-in-python/17240/4?u=fomightez) for example. ...

Comment: <continued> There's other options such as venv or pyenv, see [here](https://twitter.com/imbilltucker/status/1557504030183772160) or [here](https://twitter.com/webology/status/1557413429983444993) for information about the latter as a choice. (Note in my first comment, I should have said, "while allowing you flexibility to try new packages and versions of Python".